# Static and Media Files in Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a ImageField in my user_accounts/models.py file which i use to store the profile picture of users.It has a upload_to field which calls a function and uploads the file to a media folder in myproj/media/.. . The Image Field also has a default field which is used to set the default profile image from the static folder.
This is an entry of User Table in development server.

[image: The Avatar field shows the static url]

In The image the avatar field shows static url but when clicked it /media/ gets attached to the url before /static/ as follows:

[image: Check the url in urlbar]

In The image the url bar shows /media/ attached before the static url.When i manually remove the /media/ from the url the defaultProfileImage is shown.

This is my project structure

```
|-myproj
  |-myproj
    |-__init__.py
    |-settings.py
    |-urls.py
    |-wsgi.py
  |-static
    |-user_accounts
      |-images
        |-defaultrofileImage.png
  |-user_accounts
    |-__init__.py
    |-models.py
    |-admin.py
    |-tests.py
    |-views.py
    |-urls.py
```

Models.py File

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser



def get_upload_url(instance , filename):
    return 'userProfileImages/%s/%s'%(instance.username , filename)

class  User(AbstractUser):
    mobileNumber = models.IntegerField(blank = True , null = True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_upload_url , default = '/static/user_accounts/images/defaultProfileImage.png')

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

I have the following lines added in my settings.py file

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user_accounts.User'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This is my urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    url(r'^user/',include('user_accounts.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL , document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How should i correct the url so that when i click the url in my admin panel it shows the correct url in url bar and i get to see the defaultProfileImage??

Comment: I think you dont have `media` subidirectory so you don't need to add it to the media root: `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR` also `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`  should be just `MEDIA_URL = '/'`

Comment: that does not completely solve my problem ..now static files url gets corrected but creates a problem while serving my media files.

Comment: I think, `ImageField` default value refers to `'MEDIA_URL'`, therefore you should create `media` folder, place your default profile picture there and use `default = 'defaultProfileImage.png'` in the model field, as in your example it resolves the picture path as `MEDIA_URL + default` so you get `/media/static/...`

Comment: In that case i would be serving my defaultProfileImage from media folder but is it possible to serve it from static in any case ??

Comment: Is there any difference? The model ImageField is supposed to deal with uploaded files and by setting the default value you are setting a default uploaded file. You probably could omit `default=` from the model field and override `save` method to programmatically define the path to the `avatar`  field, but why would you overcomplicate things?

Answer (score 0):

`ImageField` default value refers to `'MEDIA_URL'`, therefore you should create `media` folder, place your `defaultProfileImage` there and use `default = 'defaultProfileImage.png'` in the model field, as in your example it resolves the picture path as `MEDIA_URL + default` so you get `/media/static/...`.

You probably could omit `default=` from the model field and override `save` method to programmatically define the path to the `avatar` field.

Usually, user-uploaded media files reside in the `MEDIA_ROOT` and static assets in `STATIC_DIRS`.

You can find more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) and read about `FileField` which is the base class of `ImageField` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField).

Comment: Media folder will automatically be created when i upload a profile pic .

Comment: If I set MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR and MEDIA_URL to '/' I am not able to srve my media files . When i click on a uploaded image url in admin that results in an error